# Can player floop Ancient Scholar when no Rainbow cards in their discard pile?

Tags: card-wars

In "Adventure time Card Wars Finn vs Jake" [Ancient Scholar](https://cardwarstcg.fandom.com/wiki/Ancient_Scholar) card has FLOOP ability

> FLOOP >>> Return a random Rainbow card from your discard pile to your hand. If you control a Building in this Lane, gain 1 Action.

Is it valid to FLOOP him when there is no Rainbow cards in discard pile? If yes, what does happen in this case?

[image: Ancient Scholar card picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes, player can FLOOP *Ancient Scholar* even if there is no Rainbow cards in their discard pile

In this case they fail to return a random Rainbow card to their hand, but still can gain *1 Action* (if control a building in the lane). This is explained in detail by [Matt Hyra](https://boardgamegeek.com/user/Matt%20Hyra) at boardgamegeek.com forum: [Flooping without fulfilling ability?](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1130422/flooping-without-fulfilling-ability)

According to the explanation, the general rule is

> you may always Floop if the ability doesn't target anything. If it requires a target, you must have a legal target before you can Floop